# AWS Glue : Spark SQL : Date expression to calculate nth date of the current quarter

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have been using the following expression in spark SQL (AWS Glue) to calculate the first date of current quarter

```
Reporting_Date >= date_trunc('QUARTER',current_date())
```

This had been working fine. Now I have to change this to 10th date of every quarter so I am trying this ( For current quarter it should give 10th October)

```
Reporting_Date >= date_trunc('QUARTER',current_date)+9
```

and this

```
Reporting_Date >= date_trunc('QUARTER',current_date())+9
```

But both are failing with

```
cannot resolve '(date_trunc('QUARTER', CAST(current_date() AS TIMESTAMP)) + 15)' due to data type mismatch
```

Please help on what expression is suitable for this.

Comment: Have you tried using https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#date_add ?